# Softkeyboard skipping typing event with multiple EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-softkeyboard

For one of feature, I'm writing an OTP sort of widget which uses multiple(say 4) Edit Text. Once you type in any one of, it reset the focus to next EditText (requestFocus()).

On **Simulator** with **computer keyboard** it is delighted to watch this & no matter how **fast** I try to fill in the blank.

But when I checked on real device with soft keyboard,it actually skip the event, looks like it's not getting focus. It needed another tap on number to enter it.

Observation: It might be because of requestFocus().

Do you see any improvement to fix it !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    Edit_otp_number1 = findViewById(R.id.edit_otp_number1);
    Edit_otp_number2 = findViewById(R.id.edit_otp_number2);
    Edit_otp_number3 = findViewById(R.id.edit_otp_number3);
    Edit_otp_number4 = findViewById(R.id.edit_otp_number4);

    Edit_otp_number1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    Edit_otp_number2.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    Edit_otp_number3.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    Edit_otp_number4.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
```

and write a text watcher like this..

```
 private final TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (Edit_otp_number1.hasFocus()) {
            Edit_otp_number2.requestFocus();
        }
        if ((Edit_otp_number2.hasFocus()) && (Edit_otp_number2.getText().length() == 1)) {
            Edit_otp_number3.requestFocus();
        }
        if (Edit_otp_number3.hasFocus() && (Edit_otp_number3.getText().length() == 1)) {
            Edit_otp_number4.requestFocus();
        }
    }
};
```